# How to Display a particular location on BingMaps in Wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I am Having a map and a textbox name txtSearch and a button name btnSearch .
I have provided a Service Refference of SearchService and GeocodeService.
How can we Find a particular location on maps after entering a Place in textbox and clicking search button.

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7! Within the section REST services - find a location by query...

Also this might help. http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/

For the Bing API you need to register to obtain a dev key.

Once you have a coordinate you have to play with `pushpins`. Hope it helps.

Comment: using the api to get the coordinates for a place the name of which you have. then use the coordinates to place a pushpin on the bing map control in your app. If you dont get the coordinates then maybe that place address is not in bing's records, and maybe you need the exact address.